# Ubuntu not starting after disabling secure boot(UEFI)

Tags: grub2

Usually I would just renable secure boot but I get a terminal screen after trying to access the boot menu. My apologies if this has been asked before but I seriously couldn't find an answer.
I have a lenovo y520 laptop and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS if that helps

EDIT : Thank you so much for the quick response. Now I have to worry about how to setup the nvidia driver
EDIT 2: It appears I have completely bricked my system. Welp, time to reinstall it.

Comment: Are you sure your machine even has secure boot?  My W520 doesn't.  If present, it would be a UEFI Settings (formerly known as BIOS settings).Read the post messages to enter the settings, maybe F1 at power up.

Comment: I did press F1 during power up, that's how I got the crash report. But yes, I do have secure boot. Is my pc totally bricked?

Comment: Both Ubuntu & Windows should work with UEFI Secure boot on or off. If Ubuntu installed with Secure boot off, then it needs the signed versions of grub & kernel to work with Secure boot on. Did Windows do an update & reset system to defaults? Check UEFI settings you changed before like AHCI and Windows setting like fast start up. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option):
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I turned off RAID mode (turned AHCI mode on) and secure boot off, but I'll try the link you sent. Much appreciated